# What is correct way to deploy single tenant app on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, devops

we have an application with FastApi backend, next.js frontend, postgresql database and cloud storage. There is possibility that in future we will add some new service to this.

For CI/CD we are using github with github actions.

Our goal is to deploy instance per client (organization), so they will be isolated, and each will have its own subdomain like `client1.ourdomain.com`, `client2.ourdomain.com` etc.

We are using Google Cloud Platform. What would be best way to deploy and manage it later?
In future we will be creating an app to manage our clients, will it be possible to turn off, or create those environments from app?

For development purpose we have virtual machine on gcp with docker-compose to run all this.

I thought about using cloud run for fastapi, cloud run for nextjs, postgres on gcp and google cloud storage. Is it correct approach?

Comment: google cloud has a concept of "project".  Would one project per tenant make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that your question is not easy to answer, because your are talking about how to handle tenancy.

A good tenancy management depends on your requirements, and the way you want to evolve and maintain your software does have big impact on that.

According to the few information you shared, organizing your clients by projects looks the way you want. That way allows you to isolate your client's resources (including accounts/billing and so on) by implementing the right IAM policies.
Also, your can later deploy a dedicated "admin" project to manage the others from an admin app.

If you have manly programming/developer skills in your team, I would suggest to talk to a GCP architect/engineer to figure out what's the right architecture to create, and to adopt a IAC approach to create your client's projects and deploys so that your app is easy to replicate and maintain across clients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As you suggested, we are organizing our clients by projects. Unfortunately, we don't have any GCP expert or devops in team. But we figured out how to solve our problems for now. As we don't have much clients, we can manage it for now.

Comment: Fine. Please consider this friendly note: make sure to learn at least the core principles of GCP IAM, to avoid common security mistakes that can put your app at risk. GCP docs and Google Cloud Skill Boost website are full of learning resources about it.